# How to hide div by value of attribute jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, attributes

I want to hide divs which has attribute `show-value` equal to 0. Something like this:

```
<div class="card-tag card-product-new-tag" show-value="0">NEW</div>//this should be hidden
<div class="card-tag card-product-new-tag" show-value="1">NEW</div>//this should be visible
```

Html:

```
<div class="card-product">
     <img class="card-product-img" src="somewhere1">
     <img class="card-product-img2" src="somewhere2">
     <div class="card-tag card-product-new-tag" show-value="0">NEW</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-sale-tag" show-value="1">SALE</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-popular-tag" show-value="1">POPULAR</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-featured-tag" show-value="1">FEATURED</div
     <div class="card-product-name"><a href="">Product Title</a></div>
     <div class="card-product-price">99TL</div>
</div>

<div class="card-product">
     <img class="card-product-img" src="somewhere1">
     <img class="card-product-img2" src="somewhere2">
     <div class="card-tag card-product-new-tag" show-value="1">NEW</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-sale-tag" show-value="1">SALE</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-popular-tag" show-value="1">POPULAR</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-featured-tag" show-value="1">FEATURED</div
     <div class="card-product-name"><a href="">Product Title</a></div>
     <div class="card-product-price">99TL</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
if ($(".card-product .card-product-new-tag").attr("show-value") == 0){
        $(".card-product .card-product-new-tag", this).hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Assuming that you have some common class to the elements which contains attribute **show-value**.

I am looping through each element and checking whether **show-value** attribute is 0. If value is zero, then i am hiding that particular element. For better understanding, please check the attached code snippet.

```js
$(".card-tag").each(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('show-value') == 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-product">
     <img class="card-product-img" src="somewhere1">
     <img class="card-product-img2" src="somewhere2">
     <div class="card-tag card-product-new-tag" show-value="0">NEW</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-sale-tag" show-value="1">SALE</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-popular-tag" show-value="1">POPULAR</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-featured-tag" show-value="1">FEATURED</div
     <div class="card-product-name"><a href="">Product Title</a></div>
     <div class="card-product-price">99TL</div>
</div>

<div class="card-product">
     <img class="card-product-img" src="somewhere1">
     <img class="card-product-img2" src="somewhere2">
     <div class="card-tag card-product-new-tag" show-value="1">NEW</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-sale-tag" show-value="1">SALE</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-popular-tag" show-value="1">POPULAR</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-featured-tag" show-value="1">FEATURED</div
     <div class="card-product-name"><a href="">Product Title</a></div>
     <div class="card-product-price">99TL</div>
</div>
```